# Is there a way to use a 2d tensor as the input for a MLP in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, mlp

I’m brand new to Pytorch, and I'm trying to train a MLP in Pytorch to classify a variable from multiple sets of timeseries data. <

```
 Example[time, a, b, c]: 
    {[0, 10, 15, 20] [1, 11, 17, 10] [2, 12, 12, 6]} -> 1 
    {[0, 10, 12, 9] [1, 15, 13, 0] [2, 18, 11, 7]} -> 2
```

Right now, I'm reshaping each of these 2d tensors to be 1d (ie [0, 10, 15, 20, 1, 11, 17, 10, 2, 12, 12, 6]) and then placing them in a Data Loader, but I'm wondering if it's possible to keep them 2d, or if there's a different way to do it?

Also, could this be the reason for my awful accuracy(both training and testing)?

Comment: As you're using an MLP, given that it is fully connected, neither the shape nor the order are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A multilayer perceptron (MLP) is a chain of dense layers. Both the input and the output of each of the layers is a one-dimensional vector. There is no way how the MLP could explicitly take into account the sequential nature of the input. On the other hand, it is very likely to learn it implicitly if the sequential properties are clear from the data. It is thus very unlikely to be the reason for the low classification accuracy.

If you want to take advantage of the sequential nature of the data, you can use an RNN over batch×3×4 tensors. However, you should find the bug causing the low accuracy first and only then experiment with making the architecture more complex.

(Just a side-note: It seems that your inputs are integer indices from some vocabulary/other categorial features. Do you use an embeddings layer first?)